# Change gnome-sound-applet icon

Tags: icons

I run a Window Manager (Awesome) for my desktop interface. I run gnome-sound-applet and I get the little applet, and it has a full black icon. However, my top panel is also black, so I can't see the icon.

How can I change the icon? Thanks. I only want to change this icon in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the sound applet icon in `/usr/share/applications`. It's owned by root so you'll need to type `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open the terminal. In the terminal window, type `sudo nautilus` to open the file manager as root so you can open the image and be able to save your changes.

Comment: On the desktop file, it had this:
Icon=multimedia-volume-control

So I went to edit /usr/share/icons/gnome/16*16/apps/multimedia-volume-control.png, but it looks nothing like what I see in the top panel.

Comment: It depends on the icon theme you are using. You might want to install the gnome-tweak tool if you're not sure what theme you are using. It will allow you to change themes also.